# Custom configuration in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

### Background

I'm writing a photo gallery, the gallery can create both previews and thumbnails.

I want the user to customize the creation of these (resolution etc)

### What I have so far

- `config/gallery.yml` - Stores the actual settings, a block for each env
- `config/initializers/gallery.rb` - Loads the YAML file into Gallery::Application
- `app/models/image.rb` - The model that reads the configuration and creates the images

### My question

Where is the best place to merge the settings with the default values?
I could either do it in `gallery.rb` or `image.rb` where it's actually used.

Otherwise, is this a sane approach or have I gone about this all wrong?
Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

### Files

#### config/initializers/gallery.yml

```
production:
  create_previews: true
  create_thumbnails: true

development:
  create_thumbnails: true
  create_previews: true

test:
  create_thumbnails: false
  create_previews: false
```

#### config/initializers/gallery.rb

```
Gallery::Application.config.image_directory = File.join(Rails.root, 'images')
Gallery::Application.config.thumbnail_directory = File.join(Rails.root, 'thumbnails')
Gallery::Application.config.preview_directory = File.join(Rails.root, 'previews')

# DO NOT MODIFY THE LINES BELOW

EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/config/gallery.yml"

if FileTest.exists? EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH
  vals = YAML.load_file(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH)[::Rails.env]
else
  vals = {}
end

Gallery::Application.config.create_previews = vals['create_previews']
Gallery::Application.config.preview_settings = vals['preview_settings']

Gallery::Application.config.create_thumbnails = vals['create_thumbnails']
Gallery::Application.config.thumbnail_settings = vals['thumbnail_settings']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also agree this is good place in config/initializers. 
but other place and way is read/write database table field in GalleryConfig ActiveRecord model using MySQL.
because easy for testcase or rails console.

Comment: I don't want to store my settings in the database, at least not now. I might add this later if I want the settings to be altered via the site.